# Connecting two android devices together via USB

Tags: android, usb

Is it possible to communicate between two android devices connected together via USB. This is assuming they are both devices with USB OTG and have kernels that support it.

I've tried searching for this but cannot find a good starting point. I'd assume that one of the devices needs to act as a host and one as a client which is exactly what I need (only really require one way communication actually).

Answer (score 3):

I tried connecting two phones (one running ICS and the other JB) using a male-A-to-male-microB cable coupled with a female-A-to-male-microB adapter, and one of the phones detected the other one as a USB device.

Whether I'd actually be able to communicate between them somehow is a different matter. Perhaps the [Android developers documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) on this subject could be of some help.

Comment: can you please add some details like which device,i will really help me

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I used two Sony XPeria devices, but since it was so long ago I can't remember which exact ones. It might have been a ZL and a P. The important part is that at least one of the phones needs to support USB host mode and run Android 3.1 or later.

Comment: Thnks, i have to connect to different samsung device,i will test and post my result also

Answer (score -1):

You can use mobodaemon for android.

Comment: If this the Mobo daemon presented in Google Play, then it connects phone to PC only.